In Python, can you get the full utility of a long decimal while only displaying two decimal places?
I have a pair of boxes. One is for labor hours. The other is for labor dollars. When you enter a labor hour amount, it automatically calculates and fills the labor dollar box. When you enter a labor dollar amount, it automatically calculates and fills the labor hours box. Everything works as desired. I use a variable.get() in the function to retrieve the data from the Entry boxes as the numbers are typed, and then update the math on a keystroke by keystroke basis.
The problem I'm running into is that when the labor dollars equate to a long decimal, the calculations go slightly awry. What ends up happening is that at a labor rate of 70.00 per hour, if I input a labor dollar amount of, for example, 127.00, it automatically fills/displays 1.81 hours of labor, which is exactly what I want to happen. But 1.81 hours of labor at 70.00 per hour comes to 126.70 because 127.00 divided by 70.00 per hour is 1.814285714285714 hours of labor, not 1.81.
As a result, the  binding, which runs by simply letting go of the tab button, causes the input labor dollars to change from 127.00 to 126.70. To get the numbers to stay the same, I need it to be able to calculate according to the full decimal number of 1.814285714285714 * 70.00, but for aesthetic purposes, I only want it to display the first two decimal places.
I don't know where to start looking to be able to calculate with the full number while displaying a truncated version.
I can offer the code I'm using as needed, but I think the question is pretty straight forward. If anyone can offer constructive guidance, it would be appreciated.
Edit: Code added
IE = {}
for i in range(117):
    IE[i] = None

def lh_1(event):
    lha = lhbox1.get()
    if lha.replace('.','',1).isnumeric() == True:
        IE[7] = float(lhbox1.get())
        IE[8] = float(IE[7])*float(ratesbox1.get())
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lbox1.insert(0, "${:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
        print(IE[7])
        print(IE[8])
    elif lhbox1.get() == ".":
        IE[7] = lhbox1.get()
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    elif lhbox1.get() == "":
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        IE[7] = None
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    else:
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lhbox1.insert(0, IE[7])
def lh_1_enter(event):
    if IE[7] != None:
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lhbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[7])))
def lh_1_leave(event):
    if IE[7] != None:
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lhbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[7])))

lhfrm1 = tkinter.Frame(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=48, height=25, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
lhfrm1.place(x=902, y=110)
lhbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=6, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
lhbox1.place(x=908, y=114)
WOBOXES.append(lhbox1)
lhbox1.bind("<KeyRelease>", lh_1)
lhbox1.bind("<FocusIn>", lh_1_enter)
lhbox1.bind("<FocusOut>", lh_1_leave)

def l_1(event):
    la = lbox1.get()
    if la.replace('.','',1).isnumeric() == True:
        IE[8] = float(lbox1.get())
        IE[7] = float(IE[8])/float(ratesbox1.get())
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lhbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(IE[7]))
        print(IE[8])
        print(IE[7])
    elif lbox1.get() == ".":
        IE[8] = lbox1.get()
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    elif lbox1.get() == "":
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        IE[8] = None
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    else:
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
def l_1_enter(event):
    if IE[8] != None:
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
def l_1_leave(event):
    if IE[8] != None:
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lbox1.insert(0, "${:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
        
lfrm1 = tkinter.Frame(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=70, height=25, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
lfrm1.place(x=952, y=110)
lbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=10, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
lbox1.place(x=958, y=114)
WOBOXES.append(lbox1)
lbox1.bind("<KeyRelease>", l_1)
lbox1.bind("<FocusIn>", l_1_enter)
lbox1.bind("<FocusOut>", l_1_leave)


You can print a number the way you like. If I print a black and white photo of myself I don't turn black and white myself... [ask] and [mre]

The answer is going to depend on the GUI toolkit you're using. A general solution might be to add a "cached" number which is full precision, and only update the cache if the user types into the corresponding box.

@nneonneo, like a dictionary? Store the value, check if there's a change on entry, and somehow exit the function if no change has been made?

It's ok and commendable to be learning. Just SO is not a replacement for reading basic tutorials. Also have you tried simply searching "python display float with 2 decimals"

@AFrazier like I said, it'll depend a bit on the GUI toolkit. For example, if you have an object for the text box, you'd store a "cached" value on that object and then have a different value for display - and only update the cache if the change event is fired.

@Julien I think the difficulty is not the display itself, but how to ensure that an editable textbox doesn't immediately overwrite the high-precision value with the low-precision value that's displayed when the user simply tabs past the field. I agree the title is not written very clearly.

@Julien, yes. I'm using float. But what I've read suggests that it's imprecise, as appears to be the case. I have a dictionary. The correct value is actually stored in it UNTIL I tab into the box. The key release triggers the function, and it takes the value from the box rather than the dictionary, because the key release has to be able to detect a change in the box. It's something of a catch 22. I explored the decimal features, but I haven't been able to find information I can understand just yet.

@nneonneo it might be, but no code provided / unclear question = no better answer possible... as you pointed yourself twice, and so did I...

@AFrazier it sounds like you have code. You should provide that code. It will make your question more answerable.

@Julian, this: "[...] ensure that an editable textbox doesn't immediately overwrite the high-precision value with the low-precision value that's displayed," absolutely. This is the problem.

Someone already closed the question. I'll post it if I can still edit it.

Okay, I've added the relevant code.

Now that's a valid looking question, although you could make the title clearer and mentioning tkinter (which I know nothing about so can't help). Voted to reopen.

I hope you can see that I'm not entirely inept. I do have programming experience. I'm just new to this programming language. I'm not looking for anyone to do the work for me. I just don't know where to find the answer to the question I'm asking. I was honestly thinking the decimal module would be the answer, but I haven't found any coherent tutorials on that.

I wonder if I could add a line to the l_h_1_enter event to capture the labor dollars in a variable so they could be reinserted when the tab release causes lhbox1 to take focus. I suppose it would depend on which takes precedent, the focus in or the key release.

Maybe @blhsing could consider reopening the question?

Maybe @Martheen could consider reopening the question?

Tagging doesn't work if the tagged haven't actually engaged in the comment thread, I only see this again because I manually check my close history

So, here's how I solved the problem.
First, I changed the event to a <KeyPress> rather than a <KeyRelease>. By doing this, it didn't automatically run the event just by tabbing into the Entry box. Releasing the tab key was triggering the <KeyRelease> event after it was already in the box, which would then cause it to variable.get() the contents of the Entry box and make the calculations that were causing my problem. But with a <KeyPress>, the event isn't triggered, because the key press happens before entering the Entry box.
Next, I added the keyboard module with a pip3 install keyboard from the cmd prompt.
Then I updated the code for the def lh_1(event) to include a simple if statement.
if keyboard.read_key() != "tab":

Once I am in the Entry box, if any key is pressed except the tab key, it runs the rest of the function, testing that the number is numeric, whether it contains a decimal, etc. But if it is the tab key, then it does nothing and the stored values in the dictionary remain the same. This essentially checks whether I'm actually changing the contents of the Entry box or just tabbing through it. The final code looks like this:
def lh_1(event):
    if keyboard.read_key() != "tab":
        lha = lhbox1.get()
        if lha.replace('.','',1).isnumeric() == True:
            IE[7] = float(lhbox1.get())
            IE[8] = float(IE[7])*float(ratesbox1.get())
            lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            lbox1.insert(0, "${:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
        elif lhbox1.get() == ".":
            IE[7] = lhbox1.get()
            lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        elif lhbox1.get() == "":
            lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            IE[7] = None
            lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        else:
            lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            lhbox1.insert(0, IE[7])
def lh_1_enter(event):
    if IE[7] != None:
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lhbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[7])))
def lh_1_leave(event):
    if IE[7] != None:
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lhbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[7])))

lhfrm1 = tkinter.Frame(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=48, height=25, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
lhfrm1.place(x=902, y=110)
lhbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=6, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
lhbox1.place(x=908, y=114)
WOBOXES.append(lhbox1)
lhbox1.bind("<KeyPress>", lh_1)
lhbox1.bind("<FocusIn>", lh_1_enter)
lhbox1.bind("<FocusOut>", lh_1_leave)

def l_1(event):
    la = lbox1.get()
    if la.replace('.','',1).isnumeric() == True:
        IE[8] = float(lbox1.get())
        IE[7] = float(IE[8])/float(ratesbox1.get())
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lhbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(IE[7]))
    elif lbox1.get() == ".":
        IE[8] = lbox1.get()
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    elif lbox1.get() == "":
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        IE[8] = None
        lhbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    else:
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
def l_1_enter(event):
    if IE[8] != None:
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lbox1.insert(0, "{:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
def l_1_leave(event):
    if IE[8] != None:
        lbox1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        lbox1.insert(0, "${:.2f}".format(float(IE[8])))
        
lfrm1 = tkinter.Frame(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=70, height=25, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
lfrm1.place(x=952, y=110)
lbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=10, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
lbox1.place(x=958, y=114)
WOBOXES.append(lbox1)
lbox1.bind("<KeyPress>", l_1)
lbox1.bind("<FocusIn>", l_1_enter)
lbox1.bind("<FocusOut>", l_1_leave)

